# "column not allowed here" error in INSERT statement

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

I created this table called LOCATION
    by doing this:

```
CREATE TABLE LOCATION(
POSTCODE VARCHAR(10) PRIMARY KEY,
STREET_NAME VARCHAR(20),
CITY VARCHAR(20));
```

and when I try to add some date within the table it doesn’t work saying there is an error

```
INSERT INTO LOCATION VALUES(PQ95VM,'HAPPY_STREET','FRANCE');
```

error is saying

> column not allowed here

Answer (score 66):

You're missing quotes around the first value, it should be

```
INSERT INTO LOCATION VALUES('PQ95VM', 'HAPPY_STREET', 'FRANCE');
```

Incidentally, you'd be well-advised to specify the column names explicitly in the INSERT, for reasons of readability, maintainability and robustness, i.e.

```
INSERT INTO LOCATION (POSTCODE, STREET_NAME, CITY) VALUES ('PQ95VM', 'HAPPY_STREET', 'FRANCE');
```

Comment: +1 especially for the advice to actually name the columns, it is a SQL antipattern to imply the columns in an insert and can have some unfortunate results indeed when the database structure schanges.

Comment: This tip put me on the right track. In my case I got this error because I was referencing an undeclared variable in the VALUES list, so that's another reason you can get it.

Answer (score 6):

I made the error of using the wrong quotation marks. I used double quotes as string delimiters in my value list instead of single quotes. Double quotes in Oracle are used as delimiters in column identifiers unlike in MySQL where they are used to enclose string literals.

```
INSERT INTO MYUSERS VALUES( 'Name', "Surname");  // Wrong

INSERT INTO MYUSERS VALUES( 'Name', 'Surname'); // Correct, Surname must be in single quotes
```

Answer (score 5):

Some time, While executing insert query, we are facing:

> Column not allowed here

error. Because of quote might missing in the string parameters. Add quote in the string params and try to execute.

Try this:

```
INSERT INTO LOCATION VALUES('PQ95VM','HAPPY_STREET','FRANCE');
```

or

```
INSERT INTO LOCATION (ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME) VALUES('PQ95VM','HAPPY_STREET','FRANCE');
```

http://www.drtuts.com/oracle-error-column-not-allowed-here/

Answer (score 4):

`INSERT INTO LOCATION VALUES(PQ95VM,'HAPPY_STREET','FRANCE');`

the above mentioned code is not correct because your first parameter POSTCODE is of type `VARCHAR(10)`. you should have used **`' '`**.

try `INSERT INTO LOCATION VALUES('PQ95VM','HAPPY_STREET','FRANCE');`

Answer (score 3):

Like Scaffman said - You are missing quotes. 
Always when you are passing a value to **varchar2** use quotes

```
INSERT INTO LOCATION VALUES('PQ95VM','HAPPY_STREET','FRANCE');
```

So one (**'**) starts the string and the second  (**'**) closes it.

But if you want to add a quote symbol into a string for example:

> My father told me: 'you have to be brave, son'.

You have to use a triple quote symbol like:

> 'My father told me: ''you have to be brave, son''.'

*adding quote method can vary on different db engines

Answer (score 3):

#### Convert double quotes (" ") to single quotes (' ')

**Example**

If you have something like this:

```
INSERT INTO clients (id, email, country)
VALUES (1, "john@gmail.com", "USA");
```

Convert it to this:

```
INSERT INTO clients (id, email, country)
VALUES (1, 'john@gmail.com', 'USA');
```

Answer (score 2):

What you missed is `" "` in postcode because it is a `varchar`.

There are two ways of inserting.

When you created a table `Table created.` and you add a row just after creating it, you can use the following method.

```
INSERT INTO table_name
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);
```

`1 row created.`

You've added so many tables, or it is saved and you are reopening it, you need to mention the table's column name too or else it will display the same error.

```
ERROR at line 2:
ORA-00984: column not allowed here


INSERT INTO table_name (column1,column2,column3,...)
VALUES (value1,value2,value3,...);
```

`1 row created.`

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Plus,we have to use single quotes('') instead of double quotes("").

Example:

insert into emp values(1,"Nilay"); // This is wrong

insert into emp values(1,'Nilay'); // This is right

Comment: Confusion with single/double quotes is not the problem here. The problem is that the first value is not quoted at all.

Answer (score 0):

This error creeps in if we make some spelling mistake in entering the variable name.
Like in stored proc, I have the variable name x and in my insert statement I am using

```
insert into tablename values(y);
```

It will throw an error column not allowed here.

Answer (score 0):

```
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in); 
String name = sc.nextLine();
String surname = sc.nextLine();
Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
String query = "INSERT INTO STUDENT VALUES("+'"name"'+","+'"surname"'+")";
statement.executeQuery();
```

Do not miss to add '"----"' when *concat* the string.

Answer (score 0):

Try using varchar2 instead of varchar and use this :

`INSERT INTO LOCATION VALUES('PQ95VM','HAPPY_STREET','FRANCE');`

Answer (score 0):

While inserting the data, we have to used character string delimiter (`' '`). And, you missed it (`' '`) while inserting values which is the reason of your error message. The correction of code is given below:

```
INSERT INTO LOCATION VALUES(PQ95VM,'HAPPY_STREET','FRANCE');
```

Answer (score 0):

I too got the same error while working with insert command. When i replaced double quotes with single quotes it worked fine

Answer (score 0):

If `PQ95VM` is supposed to be a literal string, then use `'PQ95VM'`. If it is a variable, make sure it is declared.