# Hibernate not retrieving correct value with SELECT and ORA-00984: column not allowed here error

Tags: spring, hibernate, hql, spring-4, hibernate-4.x

I am facing two issues here :

**Issue 1)** I am trying to get the `COMPANY_ID` using the `selectCompanyID` variable as shown below. I am storing the value returned into `getCompanyID` variable.When I tried to print it, as shown in the console output below, it's always printing number `1`. However, when I tried to run the actual SQL in the 
Oracle SQL developer SQL Worksheeet, I got different number. Because of this I could insert wrong ID in the following INSERT statement where it's 
getting used.

**Issue 2)** As shown in the SQL, I am also getting `ORA-00984: column not allowed here` error. Noticed, people encountering similar error in the following post :
["column not allowed here" error in INSERT statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10501521/column-not-allowed-here-error-in-insert-statement)

But here I don't have straightforward SQL INSERT statement as the one mentioned in the above post with missing quotes.

```
public boolean insertEmployeeDetails(Employee employee)
    {
        logger.debug("Starting EmployeeDaoImpl.insert()  .....");
        Session session = null;
        Transaction tx = null;
        boolean status = true;
        try {
            session = sessionFactory.openSession();
            tx = session.beginTransaction();


            //The following SELECT query returns a number when I ran it in the Oracle SQL developer SQL worksheet 

            String selectCompanyID = "SELECT"
                                        + " VALUE_EMP_ID"
                                +" FROM "
                                        + " COMPANY_DATA"
                                +" WHERE"
                                          + " testing_id = 1234"
                                +" AND "
                                          + " company_employee_id = 3345";

            int getCompanyID = session.createSQLQuery(selectCompanyID)
                           .executeUpdate();

            System.out.println("GetCompanyID Test below");
            System.out.println(getCompanyID);              



            String hqlInsert = "INSERT INTO Employee (NAME, IS_CORRECT,IS_WRONG,COMPANY_ID, TRANSACTION_ID,DEFINITION) VALUES"
                    + "( SELECT value_emp_id FROM COMPANY_DATA WHERE testing_id = 1234 AND"
                    + " company_employee_id = 3345))";


            String hqlInsert = "INSERT INTO Employee (NAME,IS_CORRECT,IS_WRONG,COMPANY_ID,TRANSACTION_ID,DEFINITION) VALUES "
                    + "("
                    +employee.getName()+","
                    +employee.getIsCorrect()+","
                    +employee.getIsWrong()+","
                    +getCompanyID+","
                    +employee.getTransactionId()+","
                    +employee.getDefinition()+")";      

            System.out.println("October 3 Checking for hqlInsert");
            System.out.println(hqlInsert);          

            int createdEntities = session.createSQLQuery( hqlInsert )
                    .executeUpdate();

            session.persist(employee);
            tx.commit();
            System.out.println("October 3 BELOW Checking for hqlInsert");
            System.out.println(hqlInsert); 

            System.out.println("Checking for CreatedEntities");
            System.out.println(createdEntities);
        } catch(Exception ex) {
            tx.rollback();
            ex.printStackTrace();
            status = false;
        } finally {
            session.close();
        }
        logger.debug("Completed EmployeeDaoImpl.insert()  .....");
        return status;
    }
```

**Console :**

```
Hibernate: 
    SELECT
        VALUE_EMP_ID 
    FROM
        COMPANY_DATA
    WHERE
        testing_id = 1234
        AND  company_employee_id = 3345
GetCompanyID Test below
1
October 3 Checking for hqlInsert
INSERT INTO Employee (NAME,IS_CORRECT,IS_WRONG,COMPANY_ID,TRANSACTION_ID,DEFINITION) VALUES (Terminology,0,0,1,0,definitionTest)
Hibernate: 
    INSERT 
    INTO
        Employee
        (NAME,IS_CORRECT,IS_WRONG,COMPANY_ID,TRANSACTION_ID,DEFINITION) 
    VALUES
        (Terminology,0,0,1,0,definitionTest)
2017-10-03 11:32:43.753  WARN 5392 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : SQL Error: 984, SQLState: 42000
2017-10-03 11:32:43.753 ERROR 5392 --- [nio-8080-exec-4] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : ORA-00984: column not allowed here
```

Here is my Entity Class `Employee.java` is as follows:

```
package abc.def.mypackage.orm

@Entity
@Table(name = "EMPLOYEE")
public class Employee {
 public int getEmployeeId() {
  return employeeId;
 }

 public void setEmployeeId(int employeeId) {
  this.employeeId = employeeId;
 }

 public String getName() {
  return name;
 }

 public void setName(String name) {
  this.name = name;
 }

 public int getIsCorrect() {
  return isCorrect;
 }

 public void setIsCorrect(int isCorrect) {
  this.isCorrect = isCorrect;
 }

 public int getIsWrong() {
  return isWrong;
 }

 public void setIsWrong(int isWrong) {
  this.isWrong = isWrong;
 }

 public int getCompanyId() {
  return companyId;
 }

 public void setCompanyId(int companyId) {
  this.companyId = companyId;
 }

 public Integer getTransactionId() {
  return transactionId;
 }

 public void setTransactionId(Integer transactionId) {
 this.transactionId = transactionId;
 }

 public String getDefinition() {
  return definition;
 }

 public void setDefinition(String definition) {
  this.definition = definition;
 }

 @Id
 @Column(name = "EMPLOYEE_ID")
 @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO, generator = "seqgen")
 @SequenceGenerator(name = "seqgen", sequenceName = "EMPLOYEE_AUTOINC_SEQ")
 private int employeeId;

 @Column(name = "NAME")
 private String name;

 @Column(name = "DEFINITION")
 private String definition;

 @Column(name = "IS_CORRECT")
 private int isCorrect;

 @Column(name = "IS_WRONG")
 private int isWrong;

 @Column(name = "COMPANY_ID")
 private int companyId;

 @Column(name = "TRANSACTION_ID", nullable = true)
 private Integer transactionId;


}
```

Comment: Why would you hand write an HSQL Insert statement (not even sure you can)? Your not really using the ORM (Hibernate) correctly. I would recommend using just plain JDBC connection to solve this problem this way.

Comment: @mdeterman If I have to use ORM in this case, could you suggest how should I proceed in a correct manner? JDBC is my last option. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try putting your `String` values `employee.getName()` and `employee.getDefinition()` in your insert statement into quotes `'`

```
String hqlInsert = "INSERT INTO Employee (NAME,IS_CORRECT,IS_WRONG,COMPANY_ID,TRANSACTION_ID,DEFINITION) VALUES "
                    + "('"
                    +employee.getName()+"',"
                    +employee.getIsCorrect()+","
                    +employee.getIsWrong()+","
                    +getCompanyID+","
                    +employee.getTransactionId()+",'"
                    +employee.getDefinition()+"')";
```