# "Column not allowed here" error in INSERT statement-ORA-00984

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-insert

I have the same error as this one : ["column not allowed here" error in INSERT statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10501521/column-not-allowed-here-error-in-insert-statement) .

My SQL table's structure looks like this:

```
CREATE TABLE login
(
    login_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    username varchar(150) NOT NULL,
    password varchar(150) NOT NULL
);

INSERT INTO login (login_id, username, password) 
VALUES ('9', 'Mukov', '1884');
INSERT INTO login (login_id, username, password) 
VALUES ('10', 'Mukre', '661');
```

Have I done something wrong?

**Edit:** even with that way it doesn't work

```
CREATE TABLE login
(
    login_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    username varchar(150) NOT NULL,
    password varchar(150) NOT NULL
);

BEGIN
    INSERT INTO login (username, password)
    VALUES ('1', 'Sukre', '1234');
    INSERT INTO login (username, password) 
    VALUES ('2', 'Pal', '123444');
END;
```

Comment: Just start with `BEGIN` and end with `END;/` for the INSERT statements.

Comment: Also, don't put quotes round the login_id values as they are integers

Comment: moment I go check this

Comment: @NickW Also, don't put quotes round the login_id values as they are integers  I didn't get this

Comment: It means they're redundant(doesn't matter whether you put or do no put)

Comment: I got it :) thanks a lot

Comment: CREATE TABLE login(
  login_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
  username varchar(150) NOT NULL,
  password varchar(150) NOT NULL
);

begin
INSERT INTO login(username , password )VALUES ('1','Sukre','1234');
INSERT INTO login(username , password ) VALUES ('2','Pal','123444');
end;

Comment: still not working ......

Comment: check [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=e8c7cf387a4526f2a1e79642a6e0371c) out. What's your IDE by the way?

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan still not working

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan the Netbeans 8.2

Comment: It's important how you invoke from that framework. Why do you need the DDL(create table statement, I suppose it's already created from an IDE)? Suppose that you might encounter problem of issuing DDL and DML from the same code block.

Comment: I create the create table statement in the oracle. I am trying to insert data from jTextField1 ,jTextField2 ,jTextField3  from java swing (netbeans) into the oracle .I press run file on JFrame. It runs.I write in the jTextfields and I press the button.

Comment: Seems you need to use a SQL Insert statement string with bind variables

Comment: If I got it right you mean this that I have in Netbeans : statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO LOGIN VALUES(" + jTextField1.getText() + ",'" + jTextField2.getText() + "'," + jTextField3.getText() + ")");

Comment: Yes, but do not use string concatenation which make your query vulnerable to injection, rather bind variables.

Comment: @BarbarosÖzhan Thank you a lot ,but english aint my first language and I can't get what you mean.Could you give me what you mean?

Comment: you're welcome @m.s . I've meant *prepared statements* for your DML such as documented [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/sql/PreparedStatement.html). In your current case, you concatenate the subststrings with an operator(`+` indeed it, which should be pipe[`|`], is wrong too). Have a nice study!

Comment: This works in Oracle, which means that your problem must be with whatever tool and/or code you are using to execute these commands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update your insert statement as -

```
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO login(login_id, username , password )VALUES (1,'Sukre','1234');
    INSERT INTO login(login_id, username , password ) VALUES (2,'Pal','123444');
END;
/
```

Comment: still not working

Comment: @m.s, this is working perfectly for me - https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=af34c9c95af2f2b9d9e3d7342eaf7f7e

Comment: still not @Ankit Bajpai

Comment: Either the answer doesn't work for you (in which case you really shouldn't accept it as it gives the wrong signal), or it does work and you should delete these comments that say it doesn't.